# Unable to search orders in admin order Grid by custom column(s) created

Tags: magento-1.9, fatal-error, order-grid

I had created 4 custom fields for the Order:

```
pgs_order_website_names
pgs_aramex_reference
pgs_aramex_shipped
pgs_aramex_shipped_date
```

I had copied Grid.php to local/Mage/

> class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid extends
>   Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid

**Constructor**

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('sales_order_grid');
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
    $this->setDefaultSort('created_at');
    $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
}
```

**The _prepareCollection() Method :**

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    $select = $collection->getSelect();
    $select->joinLeft(array(
                        'order' => Mage::getModel('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order')),
                        'order.entity_id=main_table.entity_id',
                        array(
                        'pgs_order_website_names' => 'pgs_order_website_names',
                        'pgs_aramex_reference'=>'pgs_aramex_reference',
                        'pgs_aramex_shipped'=>'pgs_aramex_shipped',
                        'pgs_aramex_shipped_date'=>'pgs_aramex_shipped_date'
                        )
                    ); 
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

**The _prepareColumns() Method**

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('pgs_order_website_names', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Ordered Websites'),
        'index' => 'pgs_order_website_names',
        'width' => '80px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'filter' => false,

    ));
    $this->addColumn('pgs_aramex_reference', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Aramex ref. No'),
        'index' => 'pgs_aramex_reference',
        'width' => '80px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'filter' => false,

    ));
    $this->addColumn('pgs_aramex_shipped', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Sent to Warehouse ?'),
        'index' => 'pgs_aramex_shipped',
        'width' => '80px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'filter' => false,

    ));
    $this->addColumn('pgs_aramex_shipped_date', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Sent to Warehouse ?'),
        'index' => 'pgs_aramex_shipped_date',
        'width' => '80px',
        'type'  => 'date',
        'filter' => false,
    ));
return parent::_prepareColumns();
```

}

Everythig is working fine if i make the 'filter' attribute to false in `$this->addColumn()` Method! But if i changed to true im getting an error :

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setColumn() on a non-object
>   The column attributes are :

```
$dateAttribute  = array(
    'type'          => 'date',
    'backend_type'  => 'date',
    'frontend_input' => 'date',
    'is_user_defined' => true,
    'label'         => 'Shipped date',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'user_defined'  => false,   
    'searchable'    => false,
    'filterable'    => true,
    'comparable'    => false,

);
```

**Magento CE 1.9**

Comment: What does your `__construct()` method look like? Also make sure you are setting to use AJAX in the construct `$this->setUseAjax(true);`  Normally filterable is default as `true` more than likely you're missing a defined index in your collection or a callback function to sort in the collection.  http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/118022/69

Comment: Use Alias in your join section, like below :

Comment: @B00MER im getting an error if tries to search any order ::Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'increment_id' in where clause is ambiguous, query was: SELECT `main_table`.*, `order`.`pgs_order_website_names`, `order`.`pgs_aramex_reference`, `order`.`pgs_aramex_shipped`, `order`.`pgs_aramex_shipped_date` FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table`
 LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_order` AS `order` ON order.entity_id=main_table.entity_id WHERE (`increment_id` LIKE '%2800%') ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 20

Comment: @Shan http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/12279/69

Comment: @B00MER Solved the problem while searching with default fields, still problem exists with custom filelds if i set 'filter'=> true

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your `__cobstruct()` method?

Comment: @B00MER i had updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Alias in your join section, like below :

```
$select->joinLeft(array(
                    'order' => Mage::getModel('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order')),
                    'order.entity_id=main_table.entity_id',
                    array(
                    'pgs_order_website_names' => 'order.pgs_order_website_names',
                    'pgs_aramex_reference'=>'order.pgs_aramex_reference',
                    'pgs_aramex_shipped'=>'order.pgs_aramex_shipped',
                    'pgs_aramex_shipped_date'=>'order.pgs_aramex_shipped_date'
                    )
```

EDIT : Also use column names with Aliases like 'filter_index'=>'main_table.increment_id' in addColumn method 
e.g.

```
 $this->addColumn('order_id', array(
'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order Id'),
'align' =>'left',
'index' => 'increment_id',
'filter_index'=>'main_table.increment_id',
```

));

Comment: I tried this already, But it was not working .. please see the comment above regarding sql integrity error

Comment: You are getting that integrity error because, 'increment_id' exists in both joining tables i.e. main_table and order tables

Comment: Please check my above edited answer @Shan

Comment: Ahsan Thanks buddy, You pointed me in right direction, Actually "order.field_name" solved my problem completely !!!

Comment: Great to hear this from you :) @Shan

Comment: Please assign my bounty. @Shan

Comment: Sorry, i forgot !!!

Comment: @MuhammadAhsanHorani : Is possible : https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/196004/57334